# Magento2 | Which procedure to upgrade to 2.2.6 in area development / GIT?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

> We have started development on a Magento CE 2.2.5 and installed theme
>   / modules and custom module. We are working with local project/server
>   versioned with GIT.
>
> The gitignore file specify to not look in vendor folder.
>
> I want to modify one time files on my local project then deploy
>   changes thought a commit on the server and work for all developers. Is
>   it possible ?
>
> - If a download 2.2.6 source files from Magento website and override    file in the GIT project, it will override composer.json and
>     composer.lock in which custom modules dependencies are specified.
> - If I run magento command from my local side, I think all developers have to run command and GIT project should blow up with local files
>     changes made by the upgrade.
>
> How could I process ?
>
> Should I merge composer.json and composer.lock with 2.2.6 composer
>   files then commit override core files and run composer upgrade on
>   server and local projects ?

Update 2018-10-15 :

After a long search, finally I gave up the main idea to only run cmd on my local side, commit and deploy without more actions from others :)
Find below the procedure I have followed :

- Save composer.json and composer.lock files version 2.2.5
- Modify gitignore file and exclude composer.json and composer.lock files
- Update locally your version of Magento from 2.2.5 to 2.2.6 following the procedure described on the official Magento website : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html
- Git commit and push all changes in the Magento core files on the development server
- Git pull on the server. Re add composer files previously saved (2.2.5).
- Run Magento update procedure with composer. As *the gitignore file specify to not look in vendor folder*, there is no conflict.

After this, your local version and server version of Magento should be 2.2.6

Then for the team :

- If there is an existing version, this is the same way as the local update (save composer files, pull git, re add composer files 2.2.5 and update to 2.2.6)
- If this a new project, sync the project, add composer files already in 2.2.6 (copy from server) then install with composer install cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run below commands

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Now commit **composer.json** and **composer.lock** file and push it in git
Then take pull in another environment and then run below command

```
composer install
```

Hope this helps you.